# Examples of icons which don't travel well?

Tags: localization, internationalization, icons

I was taught that certain icons do not translate well. For example a tick (check-mark) has no meaning in some cultures, etc.

In practice I haven't seen many instances of icons which don't travel well. It may be that the problem was overstated or that culture has globalised.

Do you have any examples of icons which have been missunderstood or even offensive in localis/zed applications?

Comment: It's hard for an untrained individual to judge how well an icon travels, because very few of us know two (or even more) cultures well enough. In other words: if your culture "understands" the tick mark, then it's very hard for you to judge if that is just your culture or an universal symbol.

Comment: Great question, but not programming related, so off topic here.

Comment: If the deployment of icons in software is not related to programming what is it related to? Localisation is a pretty substantial software development topic in many large organisations which deliver software for a global market.

Comment: To emphasize Joachim's point, try traveling overseas. Coming from the USA I was stunned at how good the iconography on Japanese signs is. Then I went to Europe where I find it...difficult. And I'm with Oded. While programmers need good icons choosing or drawing them is nopt a programming topic. No great suggestions for better places but area51 has [Graphic Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design) in commitment and [User Interface](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5728/user-interface) still in definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to enumerate all combination for all culture and all symbols.

The more simple a symbol is, the more meaning it has.  It has more than one meaning to even within one culture.

For example:

+, it is a cross; it is a plus; it is a target; it is Christianity related.  In East Asian, it is the symbol/character of ten.
-, it is a hyphen; it is a minus; it crosses out something; it is a bar. In East Asian, it is the symbol/character of one.
Swastika, an ancient symbol is widespread in East and West, mean many many things, from auspicious, Buddhism to Nazi.